# Merging more than one table into one existing table

Tags: sql-server, database

This is the table creation and insertion query

> ```
> If not exists(select * from sysobjects where name='hrs')
> Create table hrs(hr int)
>
> declare @cnt int =1
>
> while @cnt <= 12
> begin
>   insert into hrs values(@cnt)
>   set @cnt=@cnt+1
> end
> ```

The above code gives the output like
[image]

but I just want that
[image]

```
declare @cnt1 int = 1

while @cnt1<=12
begin
   EXEC('select he'+@cnt1+' = case when hr = 1 then '+@cnt1+' end from hrs')
   set @cnt1=@cnt1+1
end
```

The above code returns the 12 different table but i just want the all records in one table (without creating any new table).

So, how can i do this?

Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is probably a duplicate, but it's too unclear to help find it.

Comment: I am just asking how can I merge the 12 different tables (which is returns by the while loop) into single one table without creating any new table.
Here all the works done in while loop.

Comment: The question is clearer now with sample data and desired output.   It is a duplicate of this one:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745042/efficiently-convert-rows-to-columns-in-sql-server

Comment: Thanks for your reference but there were using the column name which is already in table record but Here I am giving the column name dynamically and here the column is not fixed its all depend loop.
With static data ofcourse its easy but its dynamic.

Comment: In that case you need to use dynamic sql.  Both to create the table, and to create the INSERT.   Check here:  http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#unknowncolumns

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here the all column are created dynamically through loop

Here are the full query

> ```
> declare @s varchar(MAX)=''
> declare @j int = 1
> while @j<=12
> begin
> if @j = 12
> Set @s = @s+'he'+convert(varchar,@j)+'=MAX(case when hr='+convert(varchar,@j)+' then '+convert(varchar,@j)+' end)'
> else
> set @s = @s+'he'+convert(varchar,@j)+'=MAX(case when hr='+convert(varchar,@j)+' then '+convert(varchar,@j)+' end),'
> set @j=@j+1
> end
> set @s = 'select '+@s+' from hrs'
> exec(@s)
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Your query doesn't make a lot of sense, but you can build a list of columns and then `exec` that:

```
declare @columns nvarchar(max)
declare @cnt int = 1
while @cnt <= 12
    begin
    set @columns = isnull(@columns + ', ', '') + 'He' + cast(@cnt as nvarchar) + 
        ' = sum(case when hr = ' + cast(@cnt as nvarchar) + ' then hr end)'
    end
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = 'select ' + @columns ' + from hr'
exec (@sql)
```

Comment: Can't answer that without the the table structure and some example data

Comment: look at my question again

Comment: Updated the answer.  Note that you don't really need a table if your column name is equal to your column value :)

Comment: Sorry i couldn't understand what are you want to say?
Please clear it.